# Артефакты при использовании AnimatorSet с CardView на Android 5-6

Tags: android, android-animation

С помощью анимации переворачиваю карту.
Анимация карты проходит правильно, но на заднем плане и вокруг появляются какие-то крывые тени или темная полоса по вертикали. На Android 4 работает исправно. Если использовать `LinerLayout` вместо `CardView` работает исправно. В чем может быть причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CardView imgFront = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_1);
CardView imgBack = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_0);

AnimatorSet setRightOut = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.flight_right_out);
AnimatorSet setLeftIn = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.flight_left_in);
if (!isBackVisible) {
    setRightOut.setTarget(imgFront);
    setLeftIn.setTarget(imgBack);
    setRightOut.start();
    setLeftIn.start();
    isBackVisible = true;
} else {
    setRightOut.setTarget(imgBack);
    setLeftIn.setTarget(imgFront);
    setRightOut.start();
    setLeftIn.start();
    isBackVisible = false;
}
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="-180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="500" />

    <!-- When the roration reach half of animation, show the card -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="250"/>

</set>
```

Comment: можете, как workaround, попробовать установить явно фон для родительского элемента

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду...сделать фон цвета глюка? Если да то это не подойдет так как под этой картой будет стек из других кар(колода). Интерестно что такой глюк только с элементом CardView.

Comment: я не совсем это имел в виду, но если под ним другие View, то мой вариант точно не подойдет

Comment: В целом проблему удалось решить. Изменив `CardView` на `LinearLayout` и спользовав атрибут         `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"` Но вопрос остается открытым почему такое происходит при использовании `CardView`?