# Анимация переворота бонусной карточки

Tags: android, анимация

Хочу сделать анимацию переворота карточки по клику на неё, как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511870/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-animatorset-%D1%81-cardview-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android-5-6).

Только по ссылке переворачивается вся область экрана, а мне хотелось бы, чтобы только один слой экрана.

На обратной стороне карточки хочу разместить другой слой с imageView
и по клику на этот второй слой снова переворачивать карточку к первому.

Может видели, в приложениях бонусная карта, по клику переворачивается и там штрих-код бывает. 
Со штрих-кодом разобрался, анимацию ни разу не делал.

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545827/android-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?rq=1)  используется ObjectAnimator, но когда он поворачивается, картинка сильно искажается и сам view-слой при повороте на 180 градусов тот же самый.

**Может есть какой класс или библиотека для такой реализации?**

Comment: Реализация реализации. Добро пожаловать в рекурсию :D

Comment: @Alban, сейчас исправлю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pavel163 дал мне наводку, где и что искать.

Пример с документации работает с фрагментами, это не подходило, так как нужно было много вьюшек с картами делать и соответственно, много фрагментных контейнеров.

Библиотека EasyFlipView глючная(v 1.0.0-1.0.2)

Нашёл библиотеку [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView), которая имеет много возможностей.

Как я добавил:

```
dependencies {
compile 'eu.davidea:flipview:1.1.3'
}
```

И добавил вьюшку так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<eu.davidea.flipview.FlipView
    android:id="@+id/mFlipView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

    android:animateFirstView="true"
    android:clickable="true"

    app:animateDesignLayoutOnly="true"
    app:animationDuration="200"
    app:initialLayoutAnimation="@anim/scale_up"
    app:initialLayoutAnimationDuration="200">

    <!-- Front Layout Goes Here -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_card_hoff" />

    <!-- Back Layout Goes Here -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_card_hoff_back" />



</eu.davidea.flipview.FlipView>


</LinearLayout>
```

На сайте разработчика написаны параметры `app`, но я не увидел, что можно прописать `android:animateFirstView="true"` и `app:animateDesignLayoutOnly="true"` и просто добавить во вьюшку наши `<include>`

Будут вопросы - попробую в комментах ответить. **Pavel163**, спасибо, что навёл в нужное русло =)

Answer (score 1):

Есть готовая библиотека [EasyFlipView](https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView)

Можно написать свою реализацию. Есть [пример](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) в документации гугла

Comment: EasyFlipView: у него даже его апк на сайте лагает, поворот даблтапом поисходит с 10й попытки, но спасибо за рыбу и удочку)

Comment: всё-таки библиотека не рабочая на данный момент (версия 1.0.2), она не тапается нормально